# Transparency in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3, transparency

I've read around that transparency might be possible in Sublime Text 3. However, I couldn't find anything in the changelogs or release notes. Was the feature implemented?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not implemented yet. But you can go ahead und make a suggestion on [userecho](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/)

If you're a Windows User, you can use the Package **SublimeTextTrans**

Comment: sep'14: link is dead

Comment: @wehal3001 thanks, I've updated the link, looks like the suggestion does not exist anymore